# python github/project organization

Tags: python, github, python-import

I've been thinking about my project's organization and wanted to share my thoughts and see if there are any better suggestions. 
I initially divided it in packages for the database logic, the "business" logic and a web interface.

By doing this I faced the issue of having the business package needing to import from the sibling database package, and this brought the problems about finding the sibling package. I will show an example of how it looks:

```
business/  
 |
 |-config/
 |  |_config1.yaml
 |  |_config2.yaml
 |  |-common/
 |  |_decorators.py
 |  |_environment.py
 |  |_logger.py 
 |
 |-handlers/
 |  |_somehandler.py
 |  |_otherhandler.py
 |
 |-nlp/
 |  |-validators/
 |  | |_validator1.py
 |  | |_validator2.py
 |  |
 |  |-analysis/
 |    |_someanalyzer.py
 |    |_otheranalysis.py
 |
 |_script1.py
 |_script2.py

database/  
 |_mongowrap.py  
 |_entities.py  
 |_mongoquery.py


webui/ (typical flask structure)
 |
 |-templates/
 |-static/
    |-css/
    |-js/
    |-img/
```

So in order to be able to find database package from business i have this common/environment.py

```
import sys
import os
from os.path import dirname

PROJECT_ROOT = os.environ['PROJECT_PATH']
PROJECT_CONFIGS = PROJECT_ROOT + '/business/config'
PROJECT_LOGS = PROJECT_ROOT + '/business/logs'

sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

I import this thingy on business/script1.py or script2.py to be able to find the sibling projects so the modules used in the script can find them and use them.

This goes as a MUST at the beggining of each script/module like script1.py or script2.py that uses the other modules/packages

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from common.environment import *

if not PROJECT_ROOT:
    print "Error, PROJECT_PATH is not set!"
    exit()

....
....
```

What do you think about this? I like the idea of separate projects, thus separate github repos, to work on them independently. Database has nothing to do with the business package, all it provides is access, connection, queries to db engine and model entities.

Im thinking that i could move the environment.py logic to the business/**init**.py maybe. If that helps me to skip the import call on each script.

the other option was to have just one repo, and everything inside that, so no sibling package issues. But that could become a huge repo in the near future, since code base is growing.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or idea!

Comment: > "that could become a huge repo in the near future"

how big?  and so what?  for comparison, the Linux (kernel code) git repo contains over 16 million lines of code and it's not a problem.  Unless you are an order of magnitude more code than that, you are optimising prematurely.

Comment: i read somewhere that it might get slow, but you've made a good point. Anyway, I still like the idea of having different projects that could be independent from each other. Im mostly concerned about my solution for the path and import issue. And if this idea of having separate repos that make up a big project is fine or not so common/ideal. Thanks anyway for sharing your thoughts!